# Sci-fi/fantasy fae book about a girl whose family place a geas on her, causing her to be unable to escape the town

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic, fairy

I'm looking for a book published between 2013 to 2019.

At the beginning of the book, the kids are all sitting around looking for someone they'll fall for, who they'll live with for a year and, if things go well, they'll marry.

The lead girl's family doesn't like the guy, so they kill him and use his blood to put a geas on her, causing her to be unable to escape the town.

A year later, he is sent back by an evil queen who is in love with him and tells him she moved on and has a child with her new guy. He finds her in fact with a new guy and child but the child isn't hers. The guy is gay.

She finds out what her family did, the murder, the geas, everything.

Before he has to go back, they get together, she gets pregnant and has his child, a daughter she names Faye Green, after her father and a nod to her magic.